# Changing background color of ListView items on Android

Tags: android, listview, colors

How can I change background color of `ListView` items on a per-item basis. When I use `android:backgroundColor` in the `ListView` item layout I can achieve this, however the list selector is no longer visible. I can make the selector visible again by setting `drawSelectorOnTop` to true but then the selector overlays the whole item.

Any ideas how to change those background colors and keep the selector?

PS I would rather not change the selector itself.

EDIT: Authors of GMail application have managed to achieve exactly this so it's definitely possible.

Comment: I have answer this here ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18917214/change-background-colour-of-current-listview-item-in-adapter-getview-method/56853441#56853441

Answer (score 37):

You have to create a different state drawable for each color you want to use.

For example: `list_selector_read.xml` and `list_selector_unread.xml`.

All you need to do is set everything to transparent except the `android:state_window_focused="false"` item.

Then when you are drawing your list you call                `setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_selector_unread/read)` for each row.

You don't set a listSelector on the ListView at all. That will maintain the default selector for your particular flavor of Android.

Comment: +1 This should be the accepted answer. And `row.setBackgroundResource()` happens either in `YourCustomArrayAdapter.getView()` OR else you can forego this altogether by simply setting  `android:background="@drawable/your_list_entry_selector"` on the outermost element of `res/layout/your_list_entry_layout.xml`.

Comment: wouldn't mind example of the code that goes into list_selector_read.xml

Comment: @Zapnologica It's a standard [Color State List resource](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource). You can always check the Android source repo online and look at their style resources for insight.

Comment: Correction: A [State List Drawable resource](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#StateList) is needed here, not a Color State List.

Answer (score 28):

This is a modification based on the above code, a simplest code:

```
private static int save = -1;

public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) { 

    parent.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

    if (save != -1 && save != position){
        parent.getChildAt(save).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    }

    save = position;                

}
```

I hope you find it useful

greetings!

Comment: works nicely. but after using this code list_seletor effect gone. ie. after using this code , when i click the list_item it's not giving clicking effect

Comment: Great solution！

Answer (score 23):

Ok, I got it to work like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@color/BackgroundColor" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

YMMV!

Answer (score 11):

No one seemed to provide any examples of doing this solely using an adapter, so I thought I would post my code snippet for displaying ListViews where the "curSelected" item has a different background:

```
final ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv);
lv.setAdapter(new BaseAdapter()
{
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = new TextView(ListHighlightTestActivity.this);
            convertView.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
            ((TextView)convertView).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        }

        convertView.setBackgroundColor((position == curSelected) ? 
            Color.argb(0x80, 0x20, 0xa0, 0x40) : Color.argb(0, 0, 0, 0));
        ((TextView)convertView).setText((String)getItem(position));

        return convertView;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return "item " + position;
    }

    public int getCount()
    {
        return 20;
    }
});
```

This has always been a helpful approach for me for when appearance of list items needs to change dynamically.

Answer (score 9):

```
mAgendaListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
//view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

for(int i=0; i<parent.getChildCount(); i++)
{
     if(i == position)
     {
               parent.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
     }
     else
     {
               parent.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
     }

 }
```

Comment: it highlights the 2 items at the same time. there is some problem in it.

Comment: the background is still in blue even if my finger leaves screen

Answer (score 8):

From the source code of **Android's 2.2** Email App:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"
        android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
    <item android:state_selected="true"
        android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_selected="false"
        android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
    <item android:state_selected="false"
        android:drawable="@color/message_item_read" />
</selector>
```

Nothing more to say...

Answer (score 7):

the easiest way is this. Inside your ListArrayAdapter just do this

```
if(your condition here) rowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#20FFFFFF"));
```

don't over complicate

Comment: this is not answering the question asked .. he wants to maintain list selector with a different background color for some rows .. your answer will remove list selector style !

Comment: @MohammadZekrallah I guess I'm a naughty boy that will not receive any gifts for Christmas

Comment: Though it doesn't answer the specific question, served a purpose in my app. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Did you mean to change the background color of the custom listitems when you click on it?

If so:

You just add the following code to your listview layout in xml.

---

> android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
>   android:listSelector="@android:drawable/list_selector_background"

---

The list selector here uses default selector which has a dark grey color.
You can make your own drawable and assign it to the list selector as above.

Hope this is what you wanted.

Answer (score 5):

Simple code to change all in layout of item (custom listview extends baseadapter):

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {

            RelativeLayout layout=(RelativeLayout) arg1.findViewById(R.id.rel_cell_left);
            layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);



        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

**Following way very slowly in the running**

```
mAgendaListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
//view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

for(int i=0; i<parent.getChildCount(); i++)
{
     if(i == position)
     {
               parent.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
     }
     else
     {
               parent.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
     }

 }
```

**Replaced by the following**

```
int pos = 0;
int save = -1;
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
            //Always set the item clicked blue background
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

            if (pos == 0) {
                if (save != -1) {
                    parent.getChildAt(save).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                }
                save = position;
                pos++;
                Log.d("Pos = 0", "Running");

            } else {
                parent.getChildAt(save).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                save = position;
                pos = 0;
                Log.d("Pos # 0", "Running");
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

By changing a code of Francisco Cabezas, I got the following:

```
private int selectedRow = -1;

...

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    parent.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundResource(R.color.orange);
    if (selectedRow != -1 && selectedRow != position) {
        parent.getChildAt(selectedRow).setBackgroundResource(R.color.black);
    }
    selectedRow = position;
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [List14 example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html). In `getView()` you can call `convertView.setBackgroundDrawable()` for each entry. You could have a class member counter to decide which background to call it with to get alternating backgrounds, for example.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. Setting BackgroundDrawable has the same effect as setting BackgroundColor - the selector is drawn first so it's hidden.

Comment: Change your `android:drawSelectorOnTop` to be `false`.

Answer (score 1):

In the list view you can add 
android:listselector=color name that you want.

this work fine in my app.

Answer (score 1):

The best tutorial on this can be found [here](http://www.oneminuteinfo.com/2012/12/android-set-selection-color-in-listview.html).

Key sections:

1. Surely call `view.setSelected(true)` in `onItemClick`, otherwise the you can't see the selected item background
2. Preserve the order of states in your selector otherwise you'll see unpredictable behavior in background colors (`state_selected` followed by `state_pressed`)

Answer (score 1):

You can do This.

```
 final List<String> fruits_list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(fruits));

    // Create an ArrayAdapter from List
    final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
            (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, fruits_list){
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
            // Get the current item from ListView
            View view = super.getView(position,convertView,parent);
            if(position %2 == 1)
            {
                // Set a background color for ListView regular row/item
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFB6B546"));
            }
            else
            {
                // Set the background color for alternate row/item
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFCCCB4C"));
            }
            return view;
        }
    };

    // DataBind ListView with items from ArrayAdapter
    lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If the `setBackgroundColor` is added for onItemClick event, it will not work unless you can put it after the click event.

Try to add debug code in the adapter's `getView` method, you will find that getView will be called again whenever you click on the screen.  So, after you set the background color, the system will redraw the screen with original setting.  Don't know why it waste resource to rebuild the screen whenever it's being click, there already have other way that we can notify the system to redraw the screen when needed.

Maybe you can add some control flag to determine the background color for individual row, then modify the getView method to set the color according to this control flag.  So, the background color will be changed when it redraw the screen.

I'm also looking for an official solution on it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all answers above .. none worked for me .. this is what worked eventually and is used in my application .. it will provide read/unread list items colors while maintaining listselector styles for both states :

```
<ListView
                android:id="@+id/list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:listSelector="@drawable/selectable_item_background_general"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                android:fadingEdge="none"
                android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
                android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />
```

**selectable_item_background_general.xml :**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime">
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/bg_item_selected_drawable" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/bg_item_selected_drawable" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

**bg_item_selected_drawable.xml :**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#12000000" />
</shape>
```

**notification_list_itemlayout.xml :**

```
<RelativeLayout 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/rowItemContainer"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingEnd="16dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgViewIcon"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:src="@drawable/cura_logo_symbol_small"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvNotificationText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgViewIcon"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgViewIcon"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imgViewIcon"
                android:textSize="@dimen/subtitle"
                android:textStyle="normal" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvNotificationTime"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tvNotificationText"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgViewIcon"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imgViewIcon"
                android:textSize="@dimen/subtitle" />
        </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Finally, in your adapter :**

```
if (!Model.Read)
    rowItemContainer.SetBackgroundColor (Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor ("#FFFDD0")); // unread color
else
    rowItemContainer.SetBackgroundColor (Android.Graphics.Color.White); // read color
```

Answer (score 0):

That's what I used (Kotlin):

```
if(blablabla == "whatever") {
    view.setBackgroundColor(getColor(context, R.color.teal_200))
} else {
    view.setBackgroundColor(getColor(context, R.color.teal_700))
}
```