# How to set highlight color for ListView item?

Tags: java, android

I have to make another highlight color for ListView item. I use custom adapter for items, and i have following code:

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:weightSum="1.0"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.13"
        android:background="@drawable/booklist_header"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="0dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewBookListBack"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/back_button" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.77"
        android:layout_height="0dp" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listViewCurrentList"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/selector"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutBooklistAdwhirl"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:layout_height="0dp" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Code for item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewBookListItemImage"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="135dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewBookListItemTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewBookListItemAuthor"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Code for selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/green" /> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/green" /> <!-- focused and pressed-->
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/green" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:drawable="@color/green" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Code for color.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="green">#006400</color>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>


</resources>
```

But I have a problem: ListView item doesn't change color by click! It has white color always. Where have I made mistake?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is how you do it:

First, in your `ListView`, put the following:

```
 android:listSelector="#00000000"
```

This makes your listSelector (the color you normally see when you click the listview) transparent.

Next, set the `LinearLayout` of your item layout to this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/selector"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
```

I had the same problem a few days ago and it took me ages to figure this out. Hopefully it works for you!

Comment: There are two lines containing `android:background`. Please correct

Answer (score 2):

You can try to add this: android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" to the definition of the ListView.

Hope this will help you!

P.S. You can optimize your main layout and remove the unnecessary layouts. You can use layoutopt for this.

Comment: Thank you. But now when I click the item than whole ListView change color for green, but I need only 1 item. How can I fix it?

Comment: Hmm, for this problem you could check here for a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562051/listview-item-background-via-custom-selector. I will also check and come back to you as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if this is late to the question, I came to a simpler solution, which I would like to share even for my future self:

In your `ListView` just set

```
android:listSelector="@drawable/selector"
```

In your List Item you need to remove the background.