# ListView item ColorFilter on Press

Tags: android, listview

I've been working on a project, and part of it includes a list view. When an item in the list view is clicked, it links to another activity. But when I tap it, there is no immediate reaction. For example, in one of my activities I have a button, and I'm using `setOnTouchListener` so that when the button is pressed, it has a color filter and one it is released, the filter goes away and the next activity opens. I want to have a similar effect with the list view item.

I've tried using `onTouchListener` on the listView to do the same task but it doesn't work. I'm using `setSelected(bool)` in order to change the background of the list view using the `android:state_selected` property in the xml file. (see here for how I was doing it [Android ListView selected item stay highlighted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16189651/android-listview-selected-item-stay-highlighted)).

But it doesn't work, as the view in the `onTouchListener` isn't the same as the view that I need (the specific list view item). So is there a way to highlight an item in a list view while it is pressed?

Comment: first of all it's better to use selector for changing color in selected state and default state instead of `onToachListener`, for your question you need write custom adapter and set selector background to list Item

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8522694/how-to-set-highlight-color-for-listview-item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to make selector for this. like,

```
list_item_selector.xml  
------------------------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_selected="false"
      android:state_pressed="false" 
      color android:color="#FF0000"/>
<item android:state_pressed="true">
 <color android:color="#AA736F6E" />
 </item>
<item android:state_selected="true"
      android:state_pressed="false">
    <color  android:color="#00000000"/>
```

an you have to set this selector in listview as well as layout for listitem. like this,

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/mylist"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:cacheColorHint="#AA736F6E"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/list_item_selector"
    android:divider="#737CA1"
    android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice">
</ListView>
```

and set in list item

hops it is work

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the late check but it did indeed work