# GridView ListSelector on focus in Android?

Tags: android, gridview, css-selectors, onfocus

The code below is what I use to create a GridView in my app. But the problem is the list selector's width and height is not equal to the icon's width and height(Image 1). The Image #2 is what I am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

try to use

```
android:listSelector="@null"
```

or you can [create your own selector.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562051/listview-item-background-via-custom-selector)

Comment: Which one is not working? custom selector or null selector? What do you mean by not working? the same result or unexpected result?

Comment: I tried to apply the android:listSelector="@null" and it didn't work, then I went to the site you put and follow their codes, it has the same result

Comment: Post your custom selector. It might help.

Comment: On second thought, it is related to your item view. If you are creating the item in an adapter. Please post your adapter code too.