# selected item on custom listview with contextual action bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-linearlayout

I recently started using android [actionbars](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) and [contextual action bars](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#CAB) (CAB).

I have just one activity which is a ListActivity. Basically I use the following code snipped to "activate" the CAB:

```
ListView listView = getListView();
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
listView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new MultiChoiceModeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position,
                                      long id, boolean checked) {
        // Here you can do something when items are selected/de-selected,
        // such as update the title in the CAB
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        // Respond to clicks on the actions in the CAB
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_delete:
                deleteSelectedItems();
                mode.finish(); // Action picked, so close the CAB
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu for the CAB
        MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.context, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
        // Here you can make any necessary updates to the activity when
        // the CAB is removed. By default, selected items are deselected/unchecked.
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        // Here you can perform updates to the CAB due to
        // an invalidate() request
        return false;
    }
});
```

The layout of the list:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/message_on_clipboard_icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minWidth="30dp"
    android:padding="7sp"
    android:src="@android:drawable/presence_online" >
</ImageView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/listitem_background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" >
    </TextView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/listitem_background"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message_length"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
            android:text="@string/message_length"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message_count"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
            android:text="@string/date_label" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date_message"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And within main.xml:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
</ListView>
```

Now if I do a long click on a list item the CAB shows up as expected:

[image: cab]

I use a MultiChoiceModeListener but unfortunately the selected list items do not change the background like in the example here (light blue background after an item is selected):

[image]

Do I have to use a custom selector? Or is there a standard procedure how android does handle this and I just need to make my LinearLayouts transparent? I also tried the following but with no success:

[ListView item background via custom selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562051/listview-item-background-via-custom-selector/2830994#2830994)

It would be great If somebody could point me in the right direction. Please let me know if you need more application code or xml files.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I've only ever tested this in CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE, but in that situation it works by doing the following.

- When you select a list item, in code, call "setItemChecked(position, checked)" method (on the ListView instance) for that item in the list.
- Add this to the XML for individual ListView items:
  `android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"`

Comment: I get a StackOverflowError if I do the following within `onItemCheckedStateChanged()`: `listView.setItemChecked(position, checked);`

Comment: nvm. it works just with: `android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"` thank you so much!

Comment: As an addition to domi´s comment: if you want to customize the look of selected rows you can do so by using your own implementation of the row´s layout, as it is described in this tutorial: http://www.marvinlabs.com/2010/10/custom-listview-ability-check-items/

Comment: The call to setItemChecked will result in StackOverflowError because calling setItemChecked in onItemCheckedStateChanged will be just calling each other infinitely.

Comment: Konsumierer's link is no longer valid.. new link: http://blog.marvinlabs.com/2010/10/29/custom-listview-ability-check-items/

Comment: For lists `listChoiceBackgroundIndicator` is a better choice.

Comment: Sure calling setItemChecked() inside onItemCheckedStateChanged will result in StackOverflow - because onItemCheckedStateChanged is called when one changes the item check status - so you create an endless loop

Comment: I am uunable to call this setItemChecked in my adapter class? How to call it and which parameter to send.

Comment: To @domi, by setting this `listView.setItemChecked(position, checked);`, your invoking the `onItemCheckedStateChanged` method again and again which results to end-less calls to the method and finally results to StackOverflowError. Hope it will resolve your query.

Comment: @jitainsharma yeah I know! already pointed out by Takeshi Kaga.

Answer (score 12):

Just create a a drawable called custom_background on the way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/highlight" android:state_activated="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/normal"/>
</selector>
```

and set as background on your parent layout:

```
android:background="@drawable/custom_background"
```

Comment: Perfect! I created the selector and applied it as grid view item background. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Only trying to support ICS devices and up but this new layout does what you are trying to achieve, in keeping the selected line highlighted.

```
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
     android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, 
     null, 
     from, 
     to,
     0);
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still meet this issue, please check your android:minSdkVersion. If it's too low, selector background color may not work.