# Contextual action bar on custom listview

Tags: android, custom-lists, contextual-action-bar

I need to implement contextual action bar on custom list view for deleting list selected items and i tried many tutorials but not getting result

```
1) contextual_menu.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/item_delete"
    android:icon="@drawable/delete"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
    android:title="Delete"
    android:titleCondensed="Delete">
</item>
</menu>

2) main_activity.xml



 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="@drawable/background"
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 tools:context=".MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/titlelayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btnbackicon"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:paddingLeft="-15dp"
        android:paddingStart="-15dp"
        android:paddingRight="-4dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:onClick="onBackIconClick"
        android:background="@drawable/back_arrow" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/gmmf_logo"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:paddingLeft="-10dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnbackicon"
        android:onClick="onImageBackClick"
        android:src="@drawable/gmmf" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/gmmf_logo"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/gmmf_logo"
        android:background="@drawable/text_bg"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="20dip"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="@color/whiteColor"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtActivityTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/titlelayout"
    android:text="Favorite Restaurants"
    android:textSize="55sp"
    android:background="@color/lightblack"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/Orange"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="serif"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/titlelayout"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/titlelayout" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtActivityTitle"></ListView>

</RelativeLayout>

3) list_row_layout.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtRestroName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/Darkorange"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtRastroType"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtRestroName"
    android:textColor="@color/whiteColor"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/viewdetails"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtRestroRating"
    android:background="@drawable/detail_button"
    android:text="View Details"
    android:textColor="@color/whiteColor"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtRestroRating"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:textColor="@color/whiteColor"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/line1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/viewdetails"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@color/whiteColor" />

</RelativeLayout>

4) CustomFavRestroAdapter.java

public class CustomFavRestroAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<FavEntityList> {

Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;
List<FavEntityList> favRestroList;
private SparseBooleanArray mSelectedItemsIds;

public CustomFavRestroAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,
                       List<FavEntityList> favRestroList) {
    super(context, resourceId, favRestroList);
    mSelectedItemsIds = new SparseBooleanArray();
    this.context = context;
    this.favRestroList = favRestroList;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView restroname;
    TextView restrotype;
    TextView restroratings;
}

public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (view == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_layout, null);
        // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
        holder.restroname = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtRestroName);
        holder.restrotype = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtRastroType);
        holder.restroratings = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtRestroRating);
        // Locate the ImageView in listview_item.xml

        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    // Capture position and set to the TextViews
    holder.restroname.setText(favRestroList.get(position).getRestaurantName());
    holder.restrotype.setText(favRestroList.get(position).getRestaurantType());
    holder.restroratings.setText(favRestroList.get(position).getRestaurantRating());

    return view;
}

@Override
public void remove(FavEntityList object) {
    favRestroList.remove(object);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public List<FavEntityList> getWorldPopulation() {
    return favRestroList;
}

public void toggleSelection(int position) {
    selectView(position, !mSelectedItemsIds.get(position));
}

public void removeSelection() {
    mSelectedItemsIds = new SparseBooleanArray();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void selectView(int position, boolean value) {
    if (value)
        mSelectedItemsIds.put(position, value);
    else
        mSelectedItemsIds.delete(position);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public int getSelectedCount() {
    return mSelectedItemsIds.size();
}

public SparseBooleanArray getSelectedIds() {
    return mSelectedItemsIds;
}
}

5) MainActivity.java

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ListView list1;
CustomFavRestroAdapter listviewadapter;
List<FavEntityList> favrestro = new ArrayList<FavEntityList>();

 String[] Restaurant_Names={"Paasha-JW Mariott Pune","RainForest","SubWay","KFC","Domino's","Pride Hotel","Blue Star"};
 String[] Restaurant_Type={"Restro Bar","Restaurant (Vegetarian)","Restaurant (Non-Vegetarian)","Restaurant (Non-Vegetarian)","Restaurant (Vegetarian)","Restaurant (Vegetarian)","Restro Bar"};
 String[] Restaurant_Rating={"Ratings 5.0","Ratings 4.8","Ratings 4.6","Ratings 4.0","Ratings 3.7","Ratings 3.5","Ratings 3.4"};

@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    for (int i = 0; i < Restaurant_Names.length; i++) {
        FavEntityList favrestros = new FavEntityList(Restaurant_Names[i], Restaurant_Type[i], Restaurant_Rating[i]);
        favrestro.add(favrestros);
    }

     list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
     listviewadapter = new CustomFavRestroAdapter(this, R.layout.list_row_layout, favrestro);
      list1.setAdapter(listviewadapter);
    list1.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
    list1.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {
            final int checkedCount = list1.getCheckedItemCount();
            // Set the CAB title according to total checked items
            mode.setTitle(checkedCount + " Selected");
            // Calls toggleSelection method from ListViewAdapter Class
            listviewadapter.toggleSelection(position);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.contextual_menu, menu);
            return true;
        }

         @Override
         public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
         }

         @Override
         public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.item_delete:
                    // Calls getSelectedIds method from ListViewAdapter Class
                    SparseBooleanArray selected = listviewadapter
                            .getSelectedIds();
                    // Captures all selected ids with a loop
                    for (int i = (selected.size() - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
                        if (selected.valueAt(i)) {
                            FavEntityList selecteditem = listviewadapter
                                    .getItem(selected.keyAt(i));
                            // Remove selected items following the ids
                            listviewadapter.remove(selecteditem);
                        }
                    }
                    // Close CAB
                    mode.finish();
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            listviewadapter.removeSelection();
        }
    });


 }

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

I have tried many answers 1) [selected item on custom listview with contextual action bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268219/selected-item-on-custom-listview-with-contextual-action-bar)

2) [contextual action bar](http://www.101apps.co.za/articles/using-the-contextual-action-mode-for-contextual-menus-in-your-apps-a-tutorial.html)

Thanks for any succession in advance

Comment: You need it on your Item LongPress?

Comment: yes, whether i have to implement SetOnItemLongCilckListener ?, but how it works then?

Answer (score 0):

In your list_row_layout.xml add the below line

```
   android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Since you have a button in your row the LongClick will not trigger, hence need to add the above line.

Also add

```
   list1.setOnItemLongClickListener(this).
```

ActionBar listeners

```
 @Override
  public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.contextual_menu.xml, menu);
    return true;
  }

 @Override
public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: ok i added listener and method onItemLongClick but what to do in this method?

Comment: did you add   android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" in your list_row_layout.xml

Comment: no , because i dont know in onItemLongClick method what should i write?

Comment: Try adding logs in all listeners whether all the methods gets triggred or not

Comment: i have debug my application , when long press on list view, list1.setOnItemLongClickListener isn't executing

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved problem

Because of Button, OnItemLongClick wasn't execute so that

I just removed button and put Image of View Detail.

thanks to @Lochana Ragupathy :)