# Background each row in listview

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to customize a `ListView` to have a default background image and highlighted background image for each single row.

However, the highlighted background image affects single rows, and the default background image affects the whole `ListView`; but I need it to affect each single row.

Could somebody tell me how to do this?

This is my code:

**layout/main.xml:**

```
<ListView
 android:id="@+id/list"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:dividerHeight="1dip"       
 android:listSelector="@drawable/bg_highlighted"
/>
```

**drawable/selector.xml:**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/bg_default"/>
<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/bg_default"/>

</selector>
```

**src/main.java:**

```
   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this,R.layout.list, mStrings); /*"Item1","Item2","Item3","Item4"*/
    ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector);
```

As default background and highlighted background I use png images.

[This is what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNLVo.png), but [this is what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdLqz.png).

Comment: See if this helps you: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2830994/1204249)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using arrayadapter would probably be better using a new class extending baseadapter and changing the background of each row from the getview method

Answer (score 1):

I did like **heepie** advised above. 
 And as I understand there is not a property that allow to set background drawable to single row of `ListView` directly. It's should be done by creating custom view in `getView` method of a custom adapter. This is my final code. May be it will be useful to someone.
**layout/main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout    
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
           android:id="@+id/my_list"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />

</LinearLayout>
```

**layout/my_list_item.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/my_textview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector"    
/>
```

**drawable/list_selector.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/bg_highlighted" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_default" />
</selector>
```

Drawable png images:

**drawable/bg_default.png:**
   [image: bg_default]

**drawable/bg_highlighted.png:**
   [image: bg_highlighted]

**src/main.java:**

```
public class main extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        MyAdapter adapter;
        ArrayList<String> mStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
        mStrings.add("Item 1");
        mStrings.add("Item 2");
        mStrings.add("Item 3");
        mStrings.add("Item 4");

        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.my_list);
        adapter = new MyAdapter(this, mStrings);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

**src/MyAdapter.java:**

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

public Activity activity;
ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

public MyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<String> d) {
    activity = a;
    data = d;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
}    

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_list_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Touch on view handle
            Log.d("", "Touched row "+position);
        }

    });

    //customizing view
    holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.my_textview);
    holder.textView.setText(data.get(position));

    return convertView;
}       

public static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView textView;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
}
```

**And this is a result**:
[image: result.png]

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see is you're actually using the item selector as the entire ListView background here:

> ```
> lv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector);
> ```

All you have to do is to set this selector as the background of the root view inside your `layout/list.xml` (the layout inflated for each item in the list)