# How to change background color of selected items in ListView?

Tags: android, android-listview

i've seen many simillar questions and every answer is very specific to the problem and no straight forward answer, or i found tutorials that show how to create a checkbox that's checked on selected items.
And i'm having trouble understanding how to do it from those codes.

I am following a tutorial found [Here](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/), and that's preaty much how my code looks only different names.

I Want to have a multipile selection ListView, when an item selected the background color is changed to mark the items i've selected.

Maybe i can acomplish this using a custom selector?
I understood the common way is to save the positions of selected and do something in the getView function.
I saw people creating ViewHolder, but i didn't really understand what it has to do with anything.
Can someone please help me?

Thank in advance,
Eric

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well i finally solved it, hope this helps someone :

What i did was created an `ArrayList<Integer>` that stores all the position of selected items, and toggle the background colors on clicks.

In my Adapter i define:

```
public ArrayList<Integer> selectedIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

With the following method :

```
    public void toggleSelected(Integer position)
{
    if(selectedIds.contains(position))
    {
        selectedIds.remove(position);


    }
    else
    {
        selectedIds.add(position);
    }
}
```

which addes\removes items from the ArrayList

In my getView method :

```
            if (selectedIds.contains(position)) {
            convertView.setSelected(true);
            convertView.setPressed(true);
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF9912"));
        }
        else
        {
            convertView.setSelected(false);
            convertView.setPressed(false);
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
```

This checks if the position is storred in the ArrayList. if it does, paint it as selected. if not, the opposite.

all is left is the OnItemClick listener, i added :

```
    ((YourAdapter)list.getAdapter()).toggleSelected(new Integer(position));
```

When YourAdapter is the adapter of your ListView

Hope this helps anyone, as it's a generic answer :)

Comment: I am facing the same problem as you did but in your solution i am unable to understand what is "list"?

Comment: It's how i named the list in `OnItemClick` event

Answer (score 0):

You can also set following selector as background to list item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/android:transparent" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/listitem_normal" />
</selector>
```

Source: [ListView item background via custom selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562051/listview-item-background-via-custom-selector)

Answer (score 0):

There is a plain XML solution. The syntax below is WRT API 15.
I used the following list item template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/item_selection">
    <ImageView />
    <.. />
</LinearLayout>
```

It points to the file item_selection.xml in res/drawable-hdpi (in Android Studio 0.8.14):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" android:state_selected="true" />
</selector>
```