# How to Apply different colors to list view items in Android

Tags: android, android-listview

I have to show list view as like below image

[image]

Here I have the view in the xml as like this

```
    <View 
    android:id="@id/margin" 
    android:background="#6DAAE9"
    android:layout_width="20.0dip" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

I Have to change this background (#6DAAE9) dynamically when list is loaded and I have to fix these colors to corresponding item even the **list items are increased**.

Can any body help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Check out my question Here might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10447238/how-to-change-background-color-of-selected-items-in-listview

Comment: I have already go through that,but my requirement is fix that color to list items even list size increased

Comment: That dosen't matter, the getView method will occur nonetheless. so dosen't matter if the item was there at the init or added later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[See this listview](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-customized-listview.html) I added list item as per odd or even row and you can do it checking position in getView() method.And you should put imageview for that and set color rather that set color to row.

```
    if(position==0){
         //here set color for imageview which position is 0
   }else if(position==1){
         //here set color for imageview which position is 1    
   }
```

....

Comment: ok thanks for your cooperation. I will implement this in my application

Answer (score 1):

Basiclly you need to edit your `getView` method.

you can use

```
 convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#6DAAE9"));
```

With your appropriate logic, meaning if you want it to be random set random color or hold an array with the order, etc.

Comment: Please accept the most releavent answer or write your own answer once you solved your problem, good day.