# changing background color of rows in listview through an adapter

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm trying to implement a gmail like selection behavior: When I click on a item, it's either selected or deselected and a custom color is drawn over the selected items. I'm using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10447238/how-to-change-background-color-of-selected-items-in-listview) as a reference.

For some reason it only works after I select/deselect a few items. After that, getView() is called and everything works as expected.
Why isn't getView() called from the beginning?

ListActivity:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(parent, view, position, id);
    mSimpleCursorAdapter.toggleSelected(new Integer(position));
}
```

Adapter:

```
 public ArrayList<Integer> selectedIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();

@Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    mCursor = (Cursor) getItem(position);
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    int col = -1;

    if(convertView == null) 
    {   
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);

        holder.mTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.titleID);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    col = mCursor.getColumnIndex(ReminderColumns.TITLE);
    holder.mTitle.setText(mCursor.getString(col));

    if (selectedIds.contains(position)) {
        convertView.setSelected(true);
        convertView.setPressed(true);
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.orange));
    }
    else
    {
        convertView.setSelected(false);
        convertView.setPressed(false);
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    }   
return convertView; 
}

public void toggleSelected(Integer position)
{
    if(selectedIds.contains(position))
    {
        selectedIds.remove(position);
    }
    else
    {
        selectedIds.add(position);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding `notifyDataSetChanged()`?

Perhaps adding it like this would help:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(parent, view, position, id);
    mSimpleCursorAdapter.toggleSelected(new Integer(position));
    mSimpleCursorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. I don't understand why it would update after a few clicks