# Changing color of selected item listview

Tags: android, android-listview, colors

i know there are other questions about this, but i cant do it well.

I have this code:

```
    StateListDrawable sld = new StateListDrawable();
    sld.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed}, new ColorDrawable(Color.rgb(0, 255, 0)));

    lv = new ListView(this);
    lv.setId(854);
    lv.setSelector(sld);
```

That is working, but it changes all rows background color, i only want to change pressed row hightlight color.

Please dont answer with xml code, i do all programmatically.

Any idea?

Comment: try changing from state_pressed to state_activated

Comment: Also, put `lv.setChoiceMode(1);`

Comment: state_activated is API lvl 11, cant use it. still doing the same.

Comment: if you post your whole code we can help you better

Comment: its a really big code, what part u need?

Answer (score 0):

It is working if you specified a "default state" ? For example

```
sld.addState(new int[] { }, white);
```

Comment: that not seems to do nothing, still changing all rows color when i press one.

Comment: Look for the answer here by eric. it works http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10447238/how-to-change-background-color-of-selected-items-in-listview

Comment: I dont want multiselection on my listview, just to change item higthlight color...

Answer (score 0):

There few methods to do that:
1. Set listView property single choice mode true.

Comment: How can i do that programmatically?

Comment: Create view holder in adapter. Then using position set whatever you want for that holder