# List View with multiple items select and deselect

Tags: android, listview, select, android-listview

I have a list view with multiple items, where i need to select and deselect the list items, and also delete the selected items.

So i have looked into the example in the below link but its for `android:minSdkVersion="11"`
but i am working on minSdkVersion="10".

Link : http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-delete-multiple-selected-items-listview-tutorial/

And yes we can do with checked text view, check box and radio button, but the requirement is like that i cannot use that.

Is there any other way that we can acheive this?

Comment: please tell ur requirement first. we cannot guess wt u need ?

Comment: @sush i need a list items to selected and deselected as given in that link,

Comment: then use that tutorial only na. why here ?

Comment: try `list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);`

Comment: @sush as i have said before its for android:minSdkVersion="11" but i am working on minSdkVersion="10".

Comment: @Ketan can you show me some example ?

Comment: @Goofy I found this line from link you provided. go there and follow it.

Answer (score 1):

Make custom list adapter and get the click of that each view and maintain flag in adapter. If flag is true that means item selected otherwise item deselected, according to that you can change item view like disable that particular item or show some check box.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was created an ArrayList that stores all the position of selected items, and toggle the background colors on clicks.

In my Adapter I define:

```
public ArrayList<Integer> selectedIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

With the following method :

```
public void toggleSelected(Integer position)
{
    if(selectedIds.contains(position))
    {
        selectedIds.remove(position);


    }
    else
    {
        selectedIds.add(position);
    }
}
```

which addes\removes items from the ArrayList

In my getView method :

```
    if (selectedIds.contains(position)) {
        convertView.setSelected(true);
        convertView.setPressed(true);
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF9912"));
    }
    else
    {
        convertView.setSelected(false);
        convertView.setPressed(false);
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    }
```

This checks if the position is storred in the ArrayList. if it does, paint it as selected. if not, the opposite.

all is left is the OnItemClick listener, i added :

```
((YourAdapter)list.getAdapter()).toggleSelected(new Integer(position));
```

When YourAdapter is the adapter of your ListView

Hope this helps anyone, as it's a generic answer :)

Thanks to **eric.itzhak** here : [How to change background color of selected items in ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10447238/how-to-change-background-color-of-selected-items-in-listview)