# how to make glow effect in my images?

Tags: android, image, gridview, glow

I created simple gridview application. Now I wish to create glow effect for my images, please help me how to create glow effect for my gird view images? if anyone know please give me some idea and sample code....

This is my present screenshot:

[image]

And this is my expected glow effect screenshot: 
[image]

source code:

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello" />
<GridView 
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>
```

GridviewExampleActivity.java

```
public class GridviewExampleActivity extends Activity
{

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
private Context mContext;

public ImageAdapter(Context c){
mContext = c;
}

public int getCount()
{

    return mThumbIds.length;
 }

public Object getItem(int position)
{ 
    return null;

}

public long getItemId(int position)
{
return 0;
                                }
// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
ImageView imageView;

if (convertView == null)
{
 imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
}
else
{
imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
                                                }
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);

return imageView;
                                }
private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.icon, R.drawable.icon,
        R.drawable.icon, R.drawable.icon,
        R.drawable.icon, R.drawable.icon,
        R.drawable.icon, R.drawable.icon,
        R.drawable.icon, R.drawable.icon};
}   

}
```

glow effect screen shot:
![enter image description here][3]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the following code to make each image in your custom view glow

the getView() function of the image adapter should be like this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
ImageView imageView;

if (convertView == null)
{
imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8); 
}
else
{
   imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
   Bitmap Image=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(),mThumbIds[position]);
        Image=Image.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888,true);
        Paint paint=new Paint();
        paint.setDither(true);
        paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
        Bitmap glow=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.glow_image);
        Bitmap bitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(Image.getWidth(),Image.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas=new Canvas(bitmap);

        canvas.drawBitmap(glow, new Rect(0,0,glow.getWidth(),glow.getHeight()), new Rect(0,0,Image.getWidth(),Image.getHeight()),paint);
        canvas.drawBitmap(Image, new Rect(0,0,Image.getWidth(),Image.getHeight()), new Rect(0+5,0+5,Image.getWidth()-5,Image.getHeight()-5),paint);



        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


   return imageView;
   }
```

R.drawable.glow_image is the png image you can use as the grow effect image

[Glow.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/23755950/green.png)

Answer (score 3):

check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562051/listview-item-background-via-custom-selector)...its a custom selector

or simply u can use this

```
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/pressedback" />
   <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/focusedback" />
   <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/focusedback" />
</selector>
```