# android animation glow effect on imageview

Tags: android

I am working on a application, where in my home page i need to give glowing and fading effect animation to a logo (imageview) i tried a lot and could not find how to give glow effect animation and i know glow effect for onclick event please help me with this issue
Thanks in advance

```
public class CustomView extends ImageView{
public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}
public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}
public CustomView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}
boolean drawGlow = false;
//this is the pixel coordinates of the screen
float glowX = 0;
float glowY = 0;
//this is the radius of the circle we are drawing
float radius = 20;
//this is the paint object which specifies the color and alpha level 
//of the circle we draw
Paint paint = new Paint();
{
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    paint.setAlpha(50);
};

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas){
    super.draw(canvas);
    if(drawGlow)
        canvas.drawCircle(glowX, glowY, radius, paint);
}
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        drawGlow = true;
    }else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
        drawGlow = false;

    glowX = event.getX();
    glowY = event.getY();
    this.invalidate();
    return true;
}
}
```

this code is for touch event i want animation

Comment: blink type animation right? you need

Comment: @come at http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11936/android-lite

Comment: thanks @Khan i found the answer

Answer (score 20):

For Glow effect check [Glow effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580052/how-to-make-glow-effect-in-my-images) and for

For blink type of animation use this it works you have to change Reapeatcount and Duration accroding to your requirement

```
AlphaAnimation  blinkanimation= new AlphaAnimation(1, 0); // Change alpha from fully visible to invisible
blinkanimation.setDuration(300); // duration - half a second
blinkanimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator()); // do not alter animation rate
blinkanimation.setRepeatCount(3); // Repeat animation infinitely
blinkanimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
```

after use as given below

```
imageview.startAnimation(blinkanimation);  or imageview.setAnimation(blinkanimation);
```

Comment: i want glowing effect not blinking effect please help me

Comment: it is for touch event in that grid view i want animation any way thanks

Comment: Is there anyway you can pause blink and start it agine?

Comment: method startAnimation(blinkanimation) is working but setAnimation does not works.

Answer (score 3):

Its simple

Make 2 sets of images one is light and another one will be sunny(Bright)

Then you can use an AlphaAnimation to animate the image.