# Show the user that an ImageView is "selected" by using a stoke/outline/glow?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, opengl-es, android-imageview

EDIT: I'm changing my question a bit, to fit what I think actually has to happen now. I believe I need to make my image glow. I found this resource: [how to make glow effect in my images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580052/how-to-make-glow-effect-in-my-images) but on IRC some users didn't think it was the best idea, but couldn't provide an alternative.

I'm trying to make a pretty complex little app, but one of the first requirements is to show the user that an imageView is selected. When the white space is selected, it should "de-select" the imageView.

How do I show that an item is selected? Right now I'm trying to show a border around my image, using padding and a background color, but this doesn't work if the image has transparency. I saw in another very similar SO question that you can use a frame and wrap each imageView inside of it, but if my background is a pattern, then this won't work. My next attempt would be to create a custom imageView and set this as a property. I've heard to maybe use openGL or something, but I have no experience at all with that. What would be the best option in this situation?

Here is my MainActivity:

```
package com.example.draggingactivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        ImageView imageView1;
        ImageView imageView2;
        ImageView imageView3;
        ImageView imageView4;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
            imageView3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
            imageView4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);

            imageView1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    FrameLayout parent = (FrameLayout) v.getParent();
                    parent.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    return false;
                }
            });
            imageView2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    FrameLayout parent = (FrameLayout) v.getParent();
                    parent.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    return false;
                }
            });
            imageView3.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    FrameLayout parent = (FrameLayout) v.getParent();
                    parent.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    return false;
                }
            });
            imageView4.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    FrameLayout parent = (FrameLayout) v.getParent();
                    parent.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

                    return false;
                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

    }
```

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="1dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:padding="1dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:padding="1dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/frameLayout1"
        android:padding="1dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT: In the end of this project I want to sort of replicate what the layout editor in eclipse in my app. So the user can "click" on a view, and see that it is the current view that is being worked on.