# Black bar behind the listview item which is being deleted - android

Tags: android, listview

I am deleting an item through my dailogfragment from database and listview through database . I am able to delete the item from the database , from the listview , and able to refresh the list with the item deleted removed from the listview .

But the problem is i am getting some type of black bar ( background behind the deleted item ) immediately after deleting the item : http://i733.photobucket.com/albums/ww331/suntuu/Capture-1.png

in the image you could see my default background is white ( theme.holo.light) , but after deleting this black background pops out at the end .

When i am executing the listview fragment again , it goes away .

I am stuck with this for a very long time now .

Here's my xml layout file :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list1"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        style="@style/AndroDev"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:paddingTop="1dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and here's my style/androdev :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <style name="AndroDev" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:background">#F7F7F7</item>

    </style>

</resources>
```

**UPDATE:**

After removing the style from my listviee this problem seems to be gone , but then i am stuck with using default background for list item background , which i want to be custom .

So how could i achieve it .

Comment: please post the code that you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO I have solved it . The problem was with using my own style for getting the custom background  for the listview item , which wasn't right .

So I implemented my custom background for listview  rows using this : 
[ListView item background via custom selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562051/listview-item-background-via-custom-selector)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In your main XML which containing ListView,

just add following property to your ListView in XML:-

```
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
```

Comment: ok , i did that , but still it's getting black , i've posted my xml file , and i am using  a custom style to set the background of each listview item . Is that the reason of this problem .

Answer (score 0):

i too faced same issue, Added below line for listview instance in Activity solved it

```
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewMain);
      listView.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT); // add this line in your code
```