# Different background just for the selected list item

Tags: android, android-listview, android-listfragment

In my application, I want to have a different background to the item which is selected in the `ListView`. In fact I don't have a plain ListView, its `ListFragment` out of which I am getting my ListView through `getListView()` method. I applied the selector programmatically like:

```
ListView listview = getListView();
listview.setSelector(R.drawable.tablet_settings_list_selector);
```

And the list selector xml is like,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="false" android:state_focused="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/tablet_menu_panel" />
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/tablet_menu_panel_ontap" />
<item android:state_activated="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/tablet_selected_menu" />
</selector>
```

This is how my list should look like:

[image: ListView with different background for selected item]

As you can see, the **selected list item has different background with an outward arrow** to it. So how can I achieve this?

Comment: The arrow sticking out is over another fragment?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562051/listview-item-background-via-custom-selector look here

Comment: @Luksprog : Yes. And thats why its kinda of a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I made a conclusion that you can not set an item selected for ever in a `ListView` or `ListFragment`. So for that, I wrote my custom BaseAdapter and solved my problem :)
For people facing similar issue, here is my BaseAdapter, focus on the **getView()** method.

```
public class ListFragmentListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

String[] items;
Context _context = null;
private TabletFragment _tabletFragmentChild;

public ListFragmentListAdapter(Context context, TabletFragment tabletFragmentChild, String[] items) {
    this.items = items;
    this._context = context;
    this._tabletFragmentChild = tabletFragmentChild;
}

    //---------------------MOST IMPORTATNT PART----------------------
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(_context).inflate(R.layout.tablet_listfragment_list_item, null);
    }

    TextView textview = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_listfragment_list_item);
    textview.setText(items[position]);

    convertView.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
    textview.setTextColor(_context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));

    if(position == _tabletFragmentChild.getSelectedItemIndex()){
        convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tablet_selected1_menu);
        textview.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    }
    return convertView;
}
    //------------------------END OF IMP PART0------------------------

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return position;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return items[position];
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    if (items == null)
        return 0;

    return items.length;
}
}
```