# My ListView background selector won't highlight the selected row

Tags: android, listview, selector

I used [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562051/listview-item-background-via-custom-selector) as a guide, but when I click a row it doesn't stay highlighted. What is wrong with my code?

score_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/score_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/keyboard"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/selector"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="#CCCCCC"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp" />
...
</RelativeLayout>
```

drawable/selector.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/highlight"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/highlight"/>
</selector>
```

score_row_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scoreRowLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/row_selector" >
...
</LinearLayout>
```

drawable/row_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/highlight" />
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@color/highlight" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

**This code now works properly.**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to use `state_activated` for your row_selector.

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, you can also clear all choices with listview.clearChoices();

I have to use this unselect all rows.