# Listview items with rounded corners

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to make listview items rectangular shape with rounded corners but what's happening with me, only first row comes with rounded corners on upper part, rest of the child listview items comes in rectangular shapes with no rounded corners. I don't know why this is happening.

Here is my listview codes:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewdoctorwithappointment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:minHeight="80dp"
    android:background="@drawable/customshapeduplicate"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:divider="#4F94CD"
    android:dividerHeight="10dp"

    android:smoothScrollbar="true"

    android:listSelector="@drawable/selector"
    android:scrollbars="none" >
</ListView>
```

And Here is my customshapeduplicatefile is this:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="rectangle"> 
    <gradient android:startColor="#ffffff" android:endColor="#ffffff" 
        android:angle="270"/> 

    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="10dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp" 
        android:topLeftRadius="10dp" android:topRightRadius="10dp"/> 
</shape>
```

And this is the image:

[image]

Comment: set round shape to layout for list item

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set the background not for the `listview` but the `custom layout` that you are using to display listview row

```
android:background="@drawable/customshapeduplicate"
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply,thanks @BaZinga, u are doing the right thing,what i was doing wrong i was setting background on listview instead of customview.xml

Comment: My answer is helpful to you that is what important :)

Comment: can u help me on this,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20755671/implementation-of-dexguard.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you use a custom list adapter. Modify the below code according to your requirements.

```
 public View getView(final int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
    final ViewHolder vh;
    vh= new ViewHolder();

    if(arg1==null )
    {
                    arg1=mInflater.inflate(R.layout.lyourcustomlayouttobe inflated, arg2,false);
            arg1.setTag(vh);
            }

    return arg1;
}
```

Your custom layout

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 android:cacheColorHint="#000000"
 android:background="@drawable/listviewbkg">
 //other items to be inlfated.
 </LinearLayout>
```

Create a drawable folder under resources. post the below xml as listviewbkg

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/pressed" />
 <item  android:state_focused="false" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/normal" />
 </selector>
```

Shape when normal under drawable with name normal.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
 <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>    
 <stroke android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#0FECFF" /><!-- #330000FF #ffffffff -->
 <gradient                               // remove the gradient if do not wish to use.
    android:startColor="#ffffffff" 
    android:endColor="#110000FF" 
    android:angle="90"/> 

 <padding android:left="5dp"
         android:top="5dp"
         android:right="5dp"
         android:bottom="5dp"/> 
 <corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"      // change this to increase the rounded edge radius
         android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" 
         android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
         android:topRightRadius="7dp"/> 
 </shape>
```

Shape when pressed under the name pressed.xml in drawable folder

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
  <solid android:color="#FF1A47"/>    
  <stroke android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#0FECFF"/>
  <padding android:left="5dp"
         android:top="5dp"
         android:right="5dp"
         android:bottom="5dp"/> 
  <corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
         android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" 
         android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
         android:topRightRadius="7dp"/> 
  </shape>
```

Comment: Is there any way in which i don't have to use custom adapter?

Comment: i suggest you use custom adapter because customization becomes easy.

Comment: Cause when i am using to put only small data i.e two textviews inside each row of listview,i am getting rectangular listview  rows rounded with ecah corner easily.

Answer (score 0):

That is because the `background`-attribute is the background of the entire list, not the individual rows.

To achieve what you want, either set a custom background through your `Adapter` or list-item layout, or look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562051/listview-item-background-via-custom-selector) answer.