# Making a custom Android ListView partially clickable

Tags: android, listview, onclick, touch-feedback

I have an Android ListView with a custom item layout:

```
|              ...              |
+-----------------+-------------+
|  Labels & Info  |  ImageView  |
+-----------------+-------------+
|              ...              |
```

I want two different actions to occur when either the left side (Labels & Info), or the right side (ImageView) of the list item are clicked. Also, the part of the item which is pressed should show accurate touch feedback (as it would highlight a ListView item by clicking on it).

I know how to implement OnClickListeners for specific views, but what I really want is to split the list item itself into two clickable areas.

How can I achieve this?

EDIT: Here is an image that should describe what I want more accurately:

[image]

The red and green areas in the item on the bottom illustrate the two areas that should be clickable and highlighted when clicked.

Comment: "but what I really want is to split the list item itself into two clickable areas." can you elaborate this.

Comment: it is better to have click listener for your views. Sample Category 1 in separate view and image in separate view and have click listener on the same. You can use selectors for individual views

Comment: I'm currently using a relative layout. You mean I should use a horizontal linearLayout which embeds another two "clickable" layouts instead?

Comment: i meant to have click listener of textview (containing labels) and for imageview

Comment: you mean you need RED part to have its own pressed and focussed states so for the GREEN part?

Comment: So how do I use selectors? Is there any good guide or tutorial out there?

Comment: @MaulikSheth I think that's what I mean.

Comment: @RafaelBankosegger http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562051/listview-item-background-via-custom-selector set the selector to both textview and imageview. search on so you will find many more related posts

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this thing, you will have to edit the getView() function of your adapter. Add the onClickListeners to respective ImageView and TextView inside it. For example:

```
@Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = convertView;
    if (rowView == null) {
      LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
      rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, null);
      ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
      viewHolder.text = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
      viewHolder.image = (ImageView) rowView
          .findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
      rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }

    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
    //Add your onClickListeners here
    //holder.text.setOnClickListner(new OnClickListner...
    //holder.iamge.setOnClickListner(new OnClickListner...

    return rowView;
  }
```

Comment: but op says "I know how to implement `OnClickListeners` for specific views"

Answer (score 0):

you can put two TextView in your layout, that match with green area and red area, and set click listener for those,and set text to "". that mean you have 5 different part, 3 part that you want to show to user and 2 part for click listener,i hope you understand my word.

Comment: its would be worked and not bad idea, and its seems to be enough.