# How do I make a specific item in the navigation drawer to appear as selected?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have been frustrated with this problem for quite a while, but I can't seem to make an item in the navigation drawer to appear as selected neither programmatically nor when the user selects it.

I am trying to achieve the following
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIHEm.png (I cannot post images yet)

I have followed the example navigation drawer at http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html
and whenever I switch fragments, I call `setItemChecked()` on the navigation drawer's `ListView`

`mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);`, but it does not seem to select the item at the position in the listview.

My layout file is also almost exactly like Google's example

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#e5e5e5" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Any help is appreciated greatly, and thanks in advance.

EDIT: Here is my initialization code for the nav-drawer. As you can see, I am not using a custom ListView or Adapter.

```
 private void setUpDrawer() {
        mDrawerListViewItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.drawer_list_item_names);
        mDrawerListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_list_item, mDrawerListViewItems));

        mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new ListView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                selectCounterFragment(position);
            }
        });

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                  /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer icon to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description */
                R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description */
                );

        // Set actionBarDrawerToggle as the DrawerListener
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        // styling option add shadow the right edge of the drawer
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
    }
```

Thank you all, for the responses so far.

Comment: do you use a custom listview?. You can use a seelctor

Comment: Nope, I'm using the built-in ListView with an ArrayAdapter. Is there a chance that it's not appearing selected because I'm using Theme.AppCompat.Light?

Comment: use a selector for `drawer_list_item.xml`

Comment: Any luck with that issue?
I am struggling with this as well. I have some kind of a workaround. I just don't use selectors and set and clear the background color by myself. Seems like a big hack and I would like to make this work with a simple selector.

I am frustrated, that this costs me so much time.

Comment: @MikeT Sadly I haven't been able to make it work with app-compat's action bar even up till now, however it works fine if I use the native action bar. I'll let you know if I get it to work.

Comment: Same issue here. Did you figure this one out?

Comment: Since you are using listview for navigation item so check this link..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562051/listview-item-background-via-custom-selector

Answer (score 0):

What is the layout for your list items? There are a number of traps with list item layouts "swallowing" state resulting in the listview not being selectable/clickable.

I would recommend taking a look at the excellent articles by [Cyril Mottier](http://cyrilmottier.com/2011/11/23/listview-tips-tricks-4-add-several-clickable-areas/), look especially at the section "Why, the hell, are my itemviews no longer clickable?"

Good luck,

CJ.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);
```

will select the 1st item on the menu.

Answer (score 0):

use `android:checked = "true"` in yournavigationlist.xml file.

**Eample:**

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
<item
        android:id="@+id/nav_main"
        android:checked="true"
        android:title="Home"
        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:title="Gallery" />

</group>
```

item with id `nav_main` will be selected by default when application starts.

Answer (score 0):

Use `navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.default)` after you setup your navigationview.

Answer (score 0):

Add

> android:checked="true"

to your specific menu item.

If you want to open specific fragment

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, new YourFragment()).commit();
```