# How to change background color of first item of a listview after setAdapter is used?

Tags: android, listview

How to change background color of first item or any other item of a listview after setAdapter is used? Basically, I want to change inside onCreate and outside of setOnItemClickListener.

***Setting List Array Adapter Code:***

```
ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(SecondActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,strings); 

    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ListView item background via custom selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562051/listview-item-background-via-custom-selector)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

you can do that in getView method at your adapter and if you use `ArrayAdapter` you can also override `getView` method as following :

```
     ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,strings){
                @Override
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                    View view;
                    if(convertView==null) {
                        LayoutInflater Inflater = (LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(MainActivity.this.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        view = Inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        view=convertView;
                    }
                    if(position==YOUR_TARGET_POSITION_TO_CHANGE_ITS_BACKGROUND)
                    {
                        view.setBackgroundColor(0x2196f3);
                    }
//Update Of textView

                    TextView txt1=(TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                text1.setText(strings[position]);

    //Rest of your code
                    return view;
                }
            };
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Comment: Also, there's no listRowLayout. I'm using ListView.

Comment: ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(SecondActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,strings);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

Comment: I want to change the color of specific items after setAdapter is used based on some conditions. But I'm unable to select an item like i can do using parent.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#2196f3")); which is used inside setOnItemClickListener

Comment: I have edited my answer and added your code to the question accept editing and try the new update and let me know if it works or not

Comment: Thank you! It helped but I don't know why text becomes invisible. Also, I changed 'new strings' to 'strings'

Comment: check new update again it's the update of text view . if it works you can approve the answer

Comment: I didn't understand why did you add TextView. There's no such textview. The text of every item becomes invisible but the number of items is still same as the length of strings.

Comment: `android.R.id.text1` is the textview of `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`  and we have overridden `getView` and we just changed the background color on it but textview isn't changed

Comment: what do you mean of that : `The text of every item becomes invisible but the number of items is still same as the length of strings`

Comment: Oh thanks! It worked! I'm new in android development so I pretty much used a lot of your time. I owe you a big one.