# exchange selector xml image

Tags: android, selector

how can I exchange new image with the currently image in selector.xml?
for example this is my selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item 
    android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/selected" />
<item 
    android:drawable="@drawable/unselected" />
</selector>
```

user will download a new image from server and the new image will exchange with the old. I.E: `new_selected` will download form server and exchange the `selected`.
Thanks.

P/S: sorry about my bad english, hope you guys understand what I'm mean.
apologize for any inconvenience.
Thank you.

Regards,

Too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have provided following solution since you are downloading image at runtime so you can not able to put it into the drawable folder so **you must need to refer image by pahtname.**

For doing this you need to write selector in code(I think so) as follow

```
OnTouchListener view1Touch = new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            v.setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(pathName));
        }
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            v.setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(pathName));
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

Comment: Hi HellBoy, another fammilar questioin here. how to I plug this function to listview? I had found a solution from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217753/changing-background-color-of-listview-items-on-android), but the problem i facing now is the the list item was not changing the image when the listview item was out of screen. e.g: Listview have 20 items. But parent.getChildCount()==10, when the user selected item more than 10 den the image didn't change. sry about my bad english, hope u understand what I'm talking about. Thanks ^^

Comment: I did not get you. If item is out of screen how you can click on it.  If it is clickable why u r not writing code on itemclicklister.