# Listview shows orange background when clicked

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm using aListview of Images (Code is not necesary, it only shows FullScreen  Images). The Listview is created dynamycally and I can't creat it on xml.

My problem comes when trying to click on an item. I dont want the orange flashy effect that it shows. Is there any way to evade the effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Changing background color of ListView items on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217753/changing-background-color-of-listview-items-on-android/2218270#2218270)

Comment: Thank you, i just found another solution, but since it's verry similar to this one, i'll accept the ansew. Thank you verry much for your time.

Comment: my solution was:

    `ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    list.setSelector(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.transparentpng10x10));
    list.setAdapter(new HoizontalGalleryAdapter(createFavories()));`

where transparentpng10x10 is a transparent png.

Answer (score 0):

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

```
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {


             LinearLayout layout=(LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.listViewLayPerRow);
                layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);




            finish();
        }
    });
```