# Keeping same background in ListView when dragging it

Tags: android, listview

I've made a ListView in my project, but I find that when I drag it up and down or I click one item, the item's background will change to be yellow(the default background in Android?). But I don't wanna to be that, I wanna: No change about the item's background when drag or click it.
   Can any way make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify a background (Color/Drawable) to the List-Item template.

Suppose you are using the default simple_list_item, it consists of only one TextView, add a background to it (instead of the default):

```
<TextView
    android:background="#000"
...
```

In this case, it will not change background when clicking or dragging.

-- Update --

In Android, the background is by default some kind of "StateListDrawable" and it will response to "State" Changes in its appearance. Specifying a background breaks the default implementation and make the background to be a simple Drawable without states.

Comment: Thank you xandy!I've try your first answer,but that seems not work.I have specified the ListView and TextView(list item) background , but nothing  changed ,anything wrong??

Comment: PS:I wanna give the TextView transparent background.('code' android:background="#00000000")

Comment: ok,I checked this site and found the solution i need.
My solution is :
   

> ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
list.setSelector(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.transparentPNG));

Note:transparentPNG is the .png file for the selector bg.

Here is the link about the solution for my problem.
[link](
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809943/listview-shows-orange-background-when-clicked)