# Android setBackground or text color for muticolumn Listview 's particular row

Tags: android, android-listview

How we set ListView's background for particular row.

```
    ListView list = getListView();
     sd = new SimpleAdapter(this, routhPath, R.layout.route_path,new String[] {"routeCode","routeName","outlets" },new int[] { R.id.routeCode,R.id.routeName,R.id.outlets});
     list.setAdapter(sd);
     list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
     list.setSelected(true);
     list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
     list.setItemsCanFocus(true);
     list.setSelectionAfterHeaderView();

     if(isVisitedToVisitHeader()){
         if(defaultRoutePos != 0){
            Log.i("-----" ,"---defaultRoutePos---" + defaultRoutePos +" --count-- "+list.getChildCount());
             list.setItemChecked(defaultRoutePos, true);
            // list.getChildAt(positions).setBackgroundColor(R.color.red);
             //list.getChildAt(defaultRoutePos).setBackgroundColor(R.color.red);
         }
     }
```

this is my code .I have done using `SimpleAdapter`.Here `list.getChildCount()` give 0.This part I am ding in the `onCreate()` .

Please help me...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not possible using the base `SimpleAdapter`. You need the fine-grained control of your own `getView()`. You have to remember that the `ListView` recycles views and that positions outside of whatever is currently visible (6 items or so, depending) do not physically exist. `listview.getChildAt()` returns to you the Nth *visible* row, so a position will not map correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout this example of Custom ListView,

[Example](http://android-codes-examples.blogspot.com/2011/03/customized-listview-items-selection.html)

Also this answer of StackOverflow

[StackOverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217753/changing-background-color-of-listview-items-on-android)

Comment: I am using muticolumn using `SimpleAdapter`.Is it possible to do using `SimpleAdapter`? please help me

Answer (score 1):

package com.android.listactivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

```
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Activity context;
    private final String[] names;

    public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Activity context, String[] names) {
        super(context, R.layout.rowlayout, names);
        this.context = context;
        this.names = names;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, null, true);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        textView.setText(names[position]);
        // Change the icon for Windows and iPhone
        String s = names[position];
```

*//Here you can do anythng with row of particular position*

```
        if (s.startsWith("Windows7") || s.startsWith("iPhone")
                || s.startsWith("Solaris")) {

            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.no);
        } else {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ok);
        }

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

I suggest to use Custom Adapter as shown above:

**If not you can try to get list.getPositionForView(view)** set background color or image for desired particular positions

Comment: NO.Its not working .I am using muticolumn using `SimpleAdapter`.Is it possible to do using `SimpleAdapter`? please help me

Comment: Have you tried to get list.getPositionForView(view) and set background color or image for desired particular positions