# Preselect items in listView Android

Tags: android, listview

All i need is an idea or path to continue searching, i have a list of items that i add to a listview adapter. And i am trying to make some items in the list to have a specific background color (as an example) when the activity loads. Something like having those rows "preselected". The method `public ListView getListView()` does not help me much.
Thank you either way.

Comment: Did this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217753/changing-background-color-of-listview-items-on-android helps you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Need to set Multiple Choice Mode via [setChoiceMode()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setChoiceMode%28int%29), and then you can call [setItemChecked()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setItemChecked%28int,%20boolean%29) for each of the items you want checked. Then you probably have to make a custom adapter that overrides [getView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29), cast the parent to ListView and ask if the View (a list item) you are getting at the position given is in fact checked by calling something like [getCheckedItems()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#getCheckedItemPositions%28%29) on the parent. Then you can do what ever you want with that view, like set its background color etc.