# setting the background color of listview programatically

Tags: android, listview, colors

I am trying to set alternate colors of an entry in a list view. I tries using setBackgroundColor and setBackgroundResource, but I seem to get only transparent background.

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                    convertView = inflateView(R.layout.pending_list);
                    if(position % 2 != 0){
                        convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_item_odd);
                    } else {
                        convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_item_even);
            }
            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

this is the list_item_odd.xml

```
<item android:state_pressed="true"><shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/blue" />
    </shape></item>
<item android:state_focused="true"><shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/blue" />
    </shape></item>
<item><shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/bluish" />
    </shape></item>
```

and this is colors.xml file

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<color name="blue">#006C9C</color>
<color name="white">#ffffff</color>
<color name="whitish">#FDFDFD</color>
<color name="bluish">#F2F9FD</color>

</resources>
```

I cant figure out why I am getting this result yet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing background color of ListView items on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217753/changing-background-color-of-listview-items-on-android)

Comment: list_item_odd.xml is an selector remove that and do it in proper way.

Comment: it worked. I had to setbackgroundresource after the null check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me

```
 private int[] listdrawable ={R.drawable.list_backgroung, R.drawable.list_backgroung1111}; //list of drawable background

    int colorPos = position % listdrawable.length;    //in getView() method before setting the values
    convertView.setBackgroundResource(listdrawable[colorPos]);

 reurn convertView;
```