# Highlighting ListView Selection

Tags: java, android, listview

I've got a (hopefully) simple question.  My program has a `ListView` to display some data. When an item is pressed, I call the `setChecked` method on it to mark it as checked.  How do I have this "checked" item appear highlighted or in a different style?  I was doing some reading on this and found a lot of things that had to do with check-boxes, but I just want to highlight an item that is "selected" by tapping it.

EDIT: I do have a selector setup as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/category_tab_s" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/category_tab"/>
</selector>
```

However, it never applies the checked state.  When I press items the `category_tab` state is activated.

Comment: in the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217753/changing-background-color-of-listview-items-on-android/ , there are couple of other code snippets that change the color , did you try them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check below link :

http://android-codes-examples.blogspot.in/2011/03/customized-listview-items-selection.html

Or on the onclick event you just set

view.setBackground("Any Color");

If your going t some other activity after clicking on any of the row and coming back again to the listview activity again refresh listview so that color get removed and you will get fresh listview.

Comment: Thanks!  It looks like that's a good starting point for me.  I still have to work with highlighting and things, but it's a start.