# Enabling an onListItemClick in a ListFragment

Tags: android, listview, actionbarsherlock, android-listfragment

I have a ListFragment that is being called from a Tab Navigation in an ActionBar.  I have a custom adapter to display two different textviews for each list item.  I'm having trouble implementing my onItemClickListener.  Here is my ListFragment code:

```
public class MaterialsListFragment extends SherlockListFragment {

    public ERGAdapter db;   

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
    ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.portrait_material_view, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // create new DBAdapter
        db = new ERGAdapter(getActivity());

        // ---- get all records
        db.open();      // Open database

        // Get all of the notes from the database and create the item list
        Cursor c = db.getAllRecords();

        String[] from = new String[] { ERGAdapter.KEY_IDNO, ERGAdapter.KEY_MATERIAL };
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.idno, R.id.materials };        

        // Now create an array adapter and set it to display using our row
        MyListAdapter materials = new MyListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_cell, c, from, to);
        setListAdapter(materials);

        // get the list view and the set the listener
        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                Log.i("MATERIAL"," - position: "+Integer.toString(position));
            }
        });
    }   

    public class MyListAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

        public MyListAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor cursor, String[] from, int[] to) {
            super(context, layout , cursor, from, to);
        }

        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {


            // Create the idno textview with background image
            TextView idno = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.idno);
            String unidno = String.format("%1$.0f", cursor.getDouble(3));
            idno.setText(unidno);

            // create the material textview
            TextView materials = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.materials);
            materials.setText(cursor.getString(1));
        }
    } 
}
```

I'm getting a fatal exception with this line: `ListView lv = getListView();`

Here is the pertinent logcat:

```
05-25 16:32:45.802: E/AndroidRuntime(660): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content view not yet created
05-25 16:32:45.802: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:328)
05-25 16:32:45.802: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.getListView(ListFragment.java:222)
05-25 16:32:45.802: E/AndroidRuntime(660):  at com.cca.ergpro.MaterialsListFragment.onCreate(MaterialsListFragment.java:80)
```

I think that I need to make it part of my custom CursorAdapter, but I'm not sure how to proceed. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working using the solution from this question:

[Creating custom simple cursor adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9690439/creating-custom-simple-cursor-adapter)