# Background Color of a list item in ListView

Tags: android

I am creating a audio player in android and showing a list of songs in a list view. I wants to change background color of currently playing song in list view. The song is changed when song is completed and in this case set background color of this song and remove background color from previous selected song in the list.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10107068/1289716

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038040/android-listview-selector-color

Comment: but how to change background color when song change by onSongFinish

Comment: See this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12610695/change-background-color-of-an-item-in-android-listactivity-onlistitemclick

Answer (score 0):

```
                yourview = v;
                v.setBackgroundResource(R.color.transparent_green);
```

Comment: but how to change background color when song change by onSongFinish

Answer (score 0):

check this [Customized ListView item's selection color](http://android-codes-examples.blogspot.in/2011/03/customized-listview-items-selection.html) with full source code how to change background color of a list view item.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.finallys.sandy;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.ColorStateList;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();

    public HelloBase mAdapter;

    LayoutInflater li;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ListView mListView = new ListView(this);
        li = getLayoutInflater();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            arr.add("this is my song" + i);
        }
        mAdapter = new HelloBase();
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        setContentView(mListView);
    }

    class HelloBase extends BaseAdapter {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return arr.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        class ViewHolder {
            TextView txt;
        }

        ViewHolder vhHolder;

        @SuppressWarnings("null")
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            vhHolder = new ViewHolder();
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
                vhHolder.txt = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.webView1);
                convertView.setTag(vhHolder);
            } else {
                vhHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            vhHolder.txt.setText(arr.get(position));
            vhHolder.txt.setOnClickListener(new OnMyClick(vhHolder.txt));
            return convertView;
        }

        class OnMyClick implements OnClickListener {

            TextView txt;

            OnMyClick(TextView txt) {
                this.txt = txt;
            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                txt.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                if (preTextView != null)
                    preTextView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

                preTextView = txt;

            }

        }
    }

    TextView preTextView;
}
```