# Android: TextView doesn't get focusable

Tags: android, focus, textview

I'm not able to figure out a really stupid issue about `TextView`!!
I have a simple Layout with a `Button` and a `TextView`. This is the Layout:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Button1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:text="TextView1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>
```

When the Button has focus and i press the "down arrow" in Emulator the TextView doesn't get the focus (it doesn't turn blue!!) Why? Please help me!!

Comment: why you want `TextView` to get focus?

Comment: what you want to do by making a `TextView` focusable ?

Comment: beacause the app is developed for not-touch devices and the TextView has to be clickable (but i don't want to use a button!)!!

Comment: @sankettt: Non focusable TextViews can't be found by screen readers, and are usually accessibility bugs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Despite the TextView doesn't turn blue, it is getting focus.

To see the focus/unfocus happening, you can, for instance, define a color change in the text. This way, these events are perceptive to the user.

Create a .xml file and put into /res/color/
In my case, i named the file as "color_text_view.xml".

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#00FF00"/>
      <item android:color="#FF00FF"/>
    </selector>
```

And add the `android:textColor="@color/color_text_view"` to the textview.

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
android:focusable="true"
android:clickable="true"
android:text="TextView1"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
android:textColor="@color/color_text_view"/>
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Thank you Renato.. You help me very much (trick you have just explanied will very usefull to me in the future).. but if i want to change the background of the TextView? I have try to replace textColor with background but i get a Runtime Error.. Is there a way to do this with this trick?

Comment: I'm not sure if this works, but take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217753/changing-background-color-of-listview-items-on-android

Comment: If I find somethig else, I let you know.

Comment: Ok. In the SO post you have linked in the previous comment there is the solution and it works fine!! thank u!

Answer (score 0):

see If you want to set your Text as focus able  then your `code is true`. your text are in focus mode but color cant' be change .

if you change color then it will set directly because you had set focus able in XML. so when app launch TextView is already in focused mode so that color will be change.