# Using exitFadeDuration cause flickering for list view custom selector

Tags: android

I have a single selection `ListView`, with each row having selector. The selector behavior is as follow. Note, the `ListView` itself also placed on a white color `LinearLayout`.

1. During normal state, the row will be white color.
2. During "selecting process", I want to let the system to handle the coloring. So, I mark them as transparent.
3. When a row item is being selected, I want the highlight color to be blue.
4. I would like to have some animation when I select from this row to that row, so I'm having `android:exitFadeDuration`

Here is how my selector looks like

```
<selector android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@drawable/blue" />

    <!-- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217753/changing-background-color-of-listview-items-on-android -->
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />     <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />     <!-- focused -->
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />    <!-- selected -->

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/white" />
</selector>
```

When I perform selection through Java code, the fading animation effect looks perfect

```
    // Highlighting.
    listView.performItemClick(getListView().getAdapter().getView(index, null, null), index, index);
    listView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            listView.setSelection(index);
        }
    }
```

**However, if I perform manual selection by clicking on the `ListView` explicitly, I can see a slightly flickering effect!**

May I know why is it so? Is there any way I can avoid this? I realize even I change the transparent state to

```
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/blue" />     <!-- pressed -->
<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/blue" />     <!-- focused -->
<item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/blue" />    <!-- selected -->
```

flickering still happen. Note, flickering effect won't be there if there is no `android:exitFadeDuration`. However, removing `android:exitFadeDuration` is not something I want.