# multiple selection listview with custom layout

Tags: android, listview, android-custom-view

I want custom ListView layout which has multiple selection , so I am doing custom adapter but how I can allow user to select multiple . In default ListView we are given choice mode but I want layout different not checkbook

```
  <Imageview>
  <Textview>
```

Do I have to manage in onItemClick or any method is der ? Small snippet will help [image]

Comment: I have answered this here, these other answers don't work in all situations - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18917214/change-background-colour-of-current-listview-item-in-adapter-getview-method/56853441#56853441

Answer (score 2):

For this you need `ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL`. See the following code snippet,

First create a ListView and it's adapter,

```
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        adapter = new AttendanceListAdapter(this, attendanceList);
```

Set the List choice mode to multiple and add a Multi choice listener,

```
        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
        listView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new ModeCallback());
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Your Multi choice listener should look something like this,

```
private class ModeCallback implements ListView.MultiChoiceModeListener {

        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.list_select_menu, menu);
            mode.setTitle("Select Items");
            return true;
        }

        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return true;
        }

        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.share:
                    Toast.makeText(AddAttendanceActivity.this, "Shared " + listView.getCheckedItemCount() +
                            " items", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mode.finish();
                    break;
                default:
                    Toast.makeText(AddAttendanceActivity.this, "Clicked " + item.getTitle(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }

        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
        }

        public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode,
                                              int position, long id, boolean checked) {
            final int checkedCount = listView.getCheckedItemCount();
            switch (checkedCount) {
                case 0:
                    mode.setSubtitle(null);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    mode.setSubtitle("One item selected");
                    break;
                default:
                    mode.setSubtitle("" + checkedCount + " items selected");
                    break;
            }
        }

    }
```

Now if you want the selected rows to highlighted add this style to the root element of your list items layout.

```
  <style name="activated" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:background">?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: setMultiChoiceModeListener is api 11+

Answer (score 0):

I think you you want something like whatsup select for that on long click listener you can change color of custom listview items(rows)

Comment: He's talking about multiple list row selection. By long press you can only highlight a single row not multiple.