# List view item background color

Tags: java, android, listview

Hello how can i set the item liner Layout background color from this array that it have just 3 color , position one color one , position two color two , position three color three and then position one color one and so on..

the position of the list view

```
int[] androidColors = context.getResources().getIntArray(R.array.randomColor);
    viewHolder.linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(androidColors[position]);
```

Comment: I think modulo operator (`position%3`) is what you are looking for.

Comment: @vishal-wadhwa thank you, that what i want

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create your own custom adapter and implement getView function like this :

```
public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
if( convertView == null ){
    //We must create a View:
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_list_item, parent, false);
}
//Here we can do changes to the convertView, such as set a text on a TextView or set the color of every single item of your view.
//or an image on an ImageView.
return convertView;
```

}

try to have a look to this post:
[Change background colour of current listview item in adapter getView method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18917214/change-background-colour-of-current-listview-item-in-adapter-getview-method)