# Change background of list item in Adapter

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, adapter

I have a recyclerView with a list of String
When a user clicks on two elements, it checks its 2 lines in a method that returns a Boolean value
if true, then 2 clicked item change background - green, otherwise red
How can I do it ?

that is, I need to change the color of the two pressed item in Adapter

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18917214/change-background-colour-of-current-listview-item-in-adapter-getview-method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change background colour of current listview item in adapter getView method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18917214/change-background-colour-of-current-listview-item-in-adapter-getview-method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside your `onBindViewHolder()` method:

```
YourObject yo = list.get(position);
holder.viewYouWantToChageBackground = holder.view.setBackgroundColor(yo.booleanCheck ? Color.Red : Color.Green);
```

Note that when user clicks, you should update your list items correctly showing which list items are pressed to correctly set the colors.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
 boolean twoitemsclicked=false;
 View firstview;
 rcview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if(!twoitemsclicked)
                    firstview=view;
                else
                {
                    //call the method
                    if(anstrue)
                    {
                        firstview.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        firstview.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    }
                }
                twoitemsclicked=!twoitemsclicked;

            }
        });
```