# How to Change background color of list item in Android?

Tags: android, listview, long-click

How to change the background color onlongclick of list item in android, now iam getting the position of the list item onlongclick by using below code.

```
 listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

     public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
             int pos, long id) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         Log.v("long clicked","pos: " + pos);

         return true;
     }
 });
```

Any help will be appriciated,, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {

                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#222222"));
                Log.v("Long Click", "Working");
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

I found a possible solution in this post: [Changing background color of ListView items on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217753/changing-background-color-of-listview-items-on-android)

```
    private static int save = -1;

public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) { 

    parent.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

    if (save != -1 && save != position){
        parent.getChildAt(save).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    }

    save = position;                

}
```

Change the method to onItemLongClick().

I hope this help!

Comment: thanks for your reply.. this solution will not work.. it will give null pointer exception

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `onItemLongClick()`

```
public View view1;// should be declared as global
if (view1 != null) {
    view1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.orange);
}
view1 = v;
v.setBackgroundResource(R.color.transparent_green);
```