# How to change the background color of ListView item while it is being pressed and not after?

Tags: android, listview, background-color, android-styles

I have a `ListView` and I want it so that when I am pressing on an item, it will change the color to dark gray. I have already tried `setSelector()`, but it keeps background color of the item even after the item is released(not being pressed anymore). I would really like to keep the selection animation on lollipop, so I would rather not use xml as you can't target just under lollipop like you can programmatically with `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT`. Is there any way to change the background color of an item only while it is being pressed programmatically or is there a way to make xml selector drawables target only certain api levels?

Comment: Hi, what type of Adapter do you use? SimpleAdapter, BaseAdapter?!?

Comment: @Neo I am using a custom adapter extending BaseAdapter

Comment: Ok, I maybe have found a solution in another Question, please Check if this helps you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217753/changing-background-color-of-listview-items-on-android?rq=1

Comment: If not, write me again, than I will write you a solution that works for your case

Comment: It pointed me in the right direction to get it solved. I declared the selector xml just like everyone else that asked this question, but instead of setting it as the `listSelector`, I set it as the background resource in the `getView` using `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)               convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_item_background);`. This also allowed me to keep the same animation for lollipop devices.

Comment: Ok, so everything is clear now? Or any other questions?

Comment: Yup. Everything is working now. Thanks for the help.