# Highlight color for row selection

Tags: android, list, view

I have got an `custom list view` with an `longclicklistener`.
i would like to set an row selection color if I tap on any row of `ListView`.
at the moment no color will be show for selection

this is my `listView`:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listViewProducts"
    android:divider="#dddddd"
    android:dividerHeight="2dp"
    android:smoothScrollbar="true"
    android:stackFromBottom="false"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:fastScrollAlwaysVisible="false"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector"/>
```

ListViewRowItem

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/row_bg"
android:paddingTop="5dp"
android:paddingBottom="5dp">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txtView1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:textSize="11sp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txtView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtView2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:textColor="@color/DefaultGreen"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:clickable="false"/>

<View
    android:layout_width="2dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="#e3e3e5"
    android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="70dp"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:id="@+id/Seperator" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/txtView3"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Seperator"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Seperator"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:textColor="@color/DefaultGreen"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:clickable="false"/>
```

Comment: the xml code isnt enough. show us at least the activity with the Listener.

Comment: i add my code to post 1

Comment: Hope Links are useful because just xml is not enough for solution.  Links (1):- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217753/changing-background-color-of-listview-items-on-android Link (2):-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976431/change-background-color-of-selected-item-on-a-listview

Comment: have you tried selector as a background

Comment: is this really so complicated? i thought i can set the default selector color via xml oO ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

then dont use the onlongclick listner in java use the selectors in xml.

add the list_selector.xml in drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/colorGreen" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorwhite" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white"/>

</selector>
```

add the color.xml in values folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <color name="colorblack">#000000</color>
    <color name="colorwhite">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="colorGreen">#55C243</color>

</resources>
```

and add the listSelector to the listview:

```
 <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" >
    </ListView>
```

[image]
see this is onclick of it

Comment: i do it like this way - but no selector color if i touch an any row

Comment: no erros, but i found something. if i set in my list view         android:drawSelectorOnTop="true", i see that the row get the selected color, but i can't see the text in this row anymore

Comment: this happens because the entire row is set to color green on top so set it to false and check :)

Comment: [http://javatechig.com/android/android-listview-tutorial] check this link you will get the basic idea of using listview from scratch

Comment: please remember that i use a custom list view not a default one

Comment: for the ListViewRowItem.xml 
add [ android:background="@drawable/list_selector" ] for the relativelyout it works :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 ListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                view.setBackgroundColor(FragementView.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGreen));
                return false;
            }
        });
```

check the above code for changing the color on long press

Comment: yes this may helps, but the color should not stay green, it should only set green as long as my finger is on the row, if my finger leave this row, the default color should be set

Comment: i have added another answer please check and let me know

Comment: look at my comment, please :)

Answer (score 0):

I kept android:background="@drawable/list_item_selector"  in main view of list row and it is working for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:drawable="@color/red" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/red" android:state_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/gray"/>
```

this is my selector

Comment: if i but this unter android:background, the background color of my whole list view will be change but not the selected row

Comment: you need to keep it in main view of 'list row' layout not in'list layout'

Comment: i added my list view.xml and my listviewrowitem.xml - what is my mistake?

Comment: add it only to you ListViewRowItem layout file

Comment: and where there? android:background="@drawable/list_item_selector" into the relative layout? if yes, this i tried, too -> nothing

Comment: maybe it would help if you update your post by adding the 'list_item_selector' xml file content and the color codes you're using for the listview/listviewitem layout files, because I got it working on my side using your 'ListViewRowItem' and 'listView' xml layouts. Also, I've noticed that you have 'android:background="@drawable/list_selector" in the list view xml file - is that needed?

Comment: i found the solution. all your ways are correct. it was my mistake, AGAIN! :D
i set the background color in the activity programmatically for testing